# Неправильный вывод в memo

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Есть массив из 10 чисел.  Пользователь вводит в поле Edit индекс элемента массива, а в Memo должно выводиться значение этого элемента. Скажите пожалуйста, почему значение выводит абсолютно неправильное?

```
procedure TForm1.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
  procedure InputLeft (var a: Tarr);
  var
    i, index: integer;
  begin
    index := strtoint(Edit1.Text);
    i := indext;
    Memo1.Text := inttostr(a[i]);
    Edit2.SetFocus;
  end;
var
  arr: Tarr;
begin
  InputLeft(arr);
end;
```

Comment: потому что `indext` это не `index`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что

```
var arr:Tarr;
```

это локальная переменная метода `TForm1.BitBtn1Click`, ничем не инициализированная и содержащая мусор.

Comment: а если у меня массив объявлен глобально, как правильно сделать?

Comment: @oyashi закомментировать строчку `var arr:Tarr;` в коде вопроса

Comment: а с каким параметром тогда вызывать процедуру InputLeft?

Comment: @oyashi с объявленным глобально массивом, естественно

Comment: Все, разобрался. Спасибо